# how to create a score based (or ranking based) column on excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKTrU.png)

**What I want to achieve**: Find the city where my tv ads have the best performance (high volume of signups at a lower cost).

**What I am doing**: In order to see the best combination of the metrics, I attributed a score for each metric column. Then, I sum all the scores (column M). The highest score is the city with the best performance.

**What I would like to do**: To automate the score columns. Is the a way to make those scores with formulas or code? (the score goes from 1 to [number of lines]). Also, I'd love to know if theres a better way to make this correlation.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a regular table, you can use `RANK()`.

So, add a column like "rank" to your table.

and put this into the first row under "rank":

```
=RANK([@[Total Score]];[Total Score];0)
```

It basically takes the total score of the current row, and checks it's ranking in the whole "total score"-column. The zero is to give the highest value the lowest rank.

Have fun! ^_^